# run a task using playbook on successful output of before task in windows

Tags: ansible

I'm executing the below YAML(ansible) file using Jenkins. I want to execute task3 only after the successful execution/output of task2 and task2 only after task1 , My YAML file is as below. How do I add the dependency for this?

For example application.yml

```
-name: task1
 win_command: "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\FRAMEWORK\V3.9.3013\MSBuild.exe" "E:\ApplicationFolder\App.xml" -target:Execute /p:ApplicationName="appname"
 register: executeapp1

-name: task2
 win_command: "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\FRAMEWORK\V3.9.3013\MSBuild.exe" "E:\ApplicationFolder\App.xml" -target:Execute /p:ApplicationName="appname1"
 register: executeapp2

-name: task3
 win_command: "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\FRAMEWORK\V3.9.3013\MSBuild.exe" "E:\ApplicationFolder\App.xml" -target:Execute /p:ApplicationName="appname1"
 register: executeapp3
```

Comment: You should check: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_handlers.html

Comment: can you clarify what should happen if one of these tasks fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example with handlers (i don't know if you need the registers on the next steps so I let them here.

```
tasks:
    - name: task1
      win_command: "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\FRAMEWORK\V3.9.3013\MSBuild.exe" "E:\ApplicationFolder\App.xml" -target:Execute /p:ApplicationName="appname"
      notify: task2
      register: executeapp1
      
 handlers:
    - name: task2
      win_command: "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\FRAMEWORK\V3.9.3013\MSBuild.exe" "E:\ApplicationFolder\App.xml" -target:Execute /p:ApplicationName="appname1"
      notify: task3
      register: executeapp2

    - name: task3
      win_command: "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\FRAMEWORK\V3.9.3013\MSBuild.exe" "E:\ApplicationFolder\App.xml" -target:Execute /p:ApplicationName="appname1"
      register: executeapp3
```

Notify will only work when the task had an exit status of "changed" so it will only be executing the notify when task 1 works.

You can also do it in a worse way using when:

```
-name: task1
 win_command: "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\FRAMEWORK\V3.9.3013\MSBuild.exe" "E:\ApplicationFolder\App.xml" -target:Execute /p:ApplicationName="appname"
 register: executeapp1

-name: task2
 win_command: "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\FRAMEWORK\V3.9.3013\MSBuild.exe" "E:\ApplicationFolder\App.xml" -target:Execute /p:ApplicationName="appname1"
 register: executeapp2
 when: task1 is changed

-name: task3
 win_command: "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\FRAMEWORK\V3.9.3013\MSBuild.exe" "E:\ApplicationFolder\App.xml" -target:Execute /p:ApplicationName="appname1"
 register: executeapp3
 when: task2 is changed
```

Comment: "worse way" solution is not as bad I think. This solves OPs requirement. I would also say why not use `block` and have these 3 tasks in that `block`?

Comment: Yes, indeed block could be used there, I'm not very used to blocks, but I don't know if you have 3 tasks in the block and 1 fails, the full block fails, or not. I Should investigate it a little bit, official doc don show to much.